# Kentico getresource 404 error css and js

Tags: kentico

Using Kentico 9, while I was away it appeared that something changed! While our production site appears to be working fine our staging site is not. When I try to access the staging site it is unable to "find" any of the related CSS or JS files and therefore displays the site without any of those files. Another part of the problem is that the same thing is happening in the admin portal and since the admin portal relies on those CSS and JS files to work I can't troubleshoot there.

When I try to get to the resource directly in a browser: e.g. iddba-staging.azurewebsites.net/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?stylesheetfile=/App_Themes/Default/bootstrap.css it fails.

When I try to access it directly at the prod site: www.iddba.org/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?stylesheetfile=/App_Themes/Default/bootstrap.css as I would expect it provides me the opportunity to save the file.

Our site(s) are hosted in Azure.

Any idea of where to turn next? Thanks.

Also on a possibly unrelated note, I have also noticed an error in the logs on staging that is not on prod:

.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - Loading profiler failed. Failed trying to receive from out of process a request to attach a profiler.

Not sure if this might be related. Thanks.

Comment: What kentico version are you running? It may have to do with your 404 handler settings. 

Can you verify that the staging site is complete, has all the files?  that the GetResources.ashx exists?

Comment: Well, that is curious as well. In the CMSPages directory there is no GetResources.ashx in either prod or staging. I am running Kentico 9.

Comment: Sorry, idiot me, forgot the GetResources.ashx is dynamic and not visible.  I'm wondering if it's just a case of something missing that usually defines it...may need to do a process of elimination.

Can you whitelist your own IP to Azure's SQL database for it, and try running the site locally? eliminate any azure web app issues?

Try doing a string compare against the production web.config and staging web.config and see if anything is different, and lastly check your site settings in case something is off.

Comment: I'm in the process of moving both sites so I can run them locally. I did do a compare between the two web.config files and the only differences were that they pointed to different databases *staging and prod' As far as I can tell there are no obvious problems with site settings however since the Admin Site won't work I did so by comparing both CMS_SettingsKey tables in the SQL server. Curious to know where GetResources.ashx gets created so I can check on that file. I did try to navigate to GetResources.ashx on each site and found that it failed immediately on Staging but not on Prod.

Answer (score 1):

Once I realized that getresource.aspx was a dynamic file and the css and js files were either already in the database or were in respective directories it looked at the dlls that power Kentico. In this case I decided to see if there were any differences in the bin directories of prod and staging. I don't know how they became out of sync but they had. Since the problems I had appeared to be serving up CSS files I noted that one file CMS.LessCss.dll was in prod and not in staging so I copied that file in. As soon as that file was copied Kentico threw an error with the word Jurassic in it (odd!). I found a file Jurassic.dll that was in Prod and not in Staging so I moved it.

Voila! The site was back, serving CSS and JS files on the front end and in administration. We are still clicking through all our pages to see if anything else is not working but for now we are good and if I have any further questions I will look in bin first since there are still files that live in prod that are not in staging and I don't want to re-populate unnecessary files. I am just not sure how the directories got out of sync in the first place... or at least no one here has admitted to having messed around! Yet.

Thanks for all your help.